ARM cortex MCU bootloader's debugging
Recently I have integrated FIH (Fault Injection Hardening) library to my MCU's bootloader.
The FIH library adds tags for debugging, FIH_CALL_START, and FIH_CALL_END for example.
For debugging purposes, I work with JLINK.
For unit-testing, of the FIH, I'd like to write some script for the debugger (over gdb I guess) to add a breakpoint by the FIH_CALL_START, change PC for example to FIH_CALL_END, and by that test the instruction skip fault injection. (Later on I'll think of more sophisticated tests).
Is anyone experienced with doing such a thing? Your assistance would be greatly appreciated //Couldn't find anything that made sense to me over the internet.
